# Why Azure Blob's lease time span limit to 60s

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

In my workflow, i want to acquire the lease to keep alive for serveral hours to make sure my most time consumption operation could success. if it is timeout, it basically means something wrong,so i need the lease will expire,  so that others can still operate/modify the blob.

why the limit is 60s? not 1 hour? or 1 day? and the parameter accept a TimeSpan, it is quite easy to use wrongly!

Answer (score 2):

> why the limit is 60s? not 1 hour? or 1 day?

As we know, if you request a lease on a Blob by calling `AcquireLease method`, the Blob will be locked until lease expires, and nobody else can modify/update the Blob while you acquired a lease on this Blob. If the default lock duration is 1 hour or longer, it will lock the Blob for a long time, once something wrong with the code and you do not release the lease by yourself, others who want to do with this Blob must wait 1 hour or longer time for your lease expired, which will not a good user experience.

If you’d like to lease the Blob for a long time, you could try to use [RenewLease method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.renewlease.aspx) to renew a lease, or you could acquire a lease for an infinite time period and explicitly release or break the lease after you complete your task.

Comment: what you describe is current fact. but you still did not explain the reason. the design for RenewLease shift the burden of manintain lock to Application, which may the whole lease logic fragile. the whole API design feels easy to use wrong and very difficult to use correctly.

Comment: I agree with @RyanShao - I fully understand not wanting excessively long-life'd leases, but then Azure should not have allowed for infinite-life-leases. We can always use the Break Lease operation to work-around a lost lease-handle, so the 60 minute limit seems arbitrary and unnecessarily limiting.